# OpenGL Rendering Issues with Ignition Gazebo in Docker on Mac Monterey

Tags: docker, opengl, ros2, gazebo-simu, xquartz

**Environment:**

- Host OS: macOS Monterey v12.6
- Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics 630 (1536 MB)
- Docker OS/Kernel: Linux 130ae26988e4 (6.5.11-linuxkit)
- Display: Using XQuartz for X11 forwarding

**Issue:**
Running ROS 2 Iron in a Docker container works fine until attempting to use Ignition Gazebo (Fortress version) with a test project. The following errors are encountered when running

```
ign gazebo building_robot.sdf
```

`root@130ae26988e4:/# ign gazebo building_robot.sdf`

`QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'`

`libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found`

`libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast`

`[GUI] [Err] [Application.cc:801] [QT] Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile)`

`... [stack trace continues] ...`

if i try same with ros2 testing node

```
ros2 run turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

it will work, i will see desplayed turtle (so it seems problem with Gazebo), but some errors still persist:
`QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'`
`libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found`
`libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast`

- I ensured XQuartz is correctly installed and configured
- I checked Docker container's access to host's X server

**Questions:**

1. Are there known compatibility issues between Ignition Gazebo and macOS's graphic system?
2. How can the **`libGL`** errors be resolved to enable proper rendering in Ignition Gazebo within a Docker container?
3. Are additional configuration steps required for Docker or XQuartz to handle OpenGL rendering for Ignition Gazebo?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: if it possible, please provide reliable ros2:iron+gazebo docker image.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, gazebo fortress dont work with mac graphics setup, (nor from the docker container, nor from the actual host) issue:
https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/issues/44
As far as I can see source of the problem openGL interaction.

If you still want to use Gazebo on mac, you can install older version (gazebo classic):
https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install&tut=install_on_mac
or try VM setup.

UPD (goto for me, my computer cannot work long with VM, start heating up): use robostack https://robostack.github.io/GettingStarted.html#__tabbed_1_1 OS agnostic decision.